# How to ensure only one instance of an winform application C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0

I dont know how to create a winform application which has only one instance anytime. Could someone please help me how to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Mutex class 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx
It is allowed to create only one instance of Mutex with same name on a machine.